# How to get all registered routes in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a web application built using Node.js and Express. Now I would like to list all registered routes with their appropriate methods.

E.g., if I have executed

```
app.get('/', function (...) { ... });
app.get('/foo/:id', function (...) { ... });
app.post('/foo/:id', function (...) { ... });
```

I would like to retrieve an object (or something equivalent to that) such as:

```
{
  get: [ '/', '/foo/:id' ],
  post: [ '/foo/:id' ]
}
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: All of the solutions I tried, do not work when you have Routers defined. It only works per route - which does not give me the entire url for that route in my app...

Comment: @guymograbi you might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55589657/6693775

Comment: I created [collect-express-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/collect-express-routes) which works on both express app and express.Router

Answer (score 316, accepted):

## express 3.x

Okay, found it myself ... it's just `app.routes` :-)

## express 4.x

[Applications](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express) - built with `express()`

> `app._router.stack`

[Routers](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router) - built with `express.Router()`

> `router.stack`

**Note**: The stack includes the middleware functions too, it should be filtered to get the *"routes"* only.

Comment: I am using node 0.10 and it was `app.routes.routes` - which means I could do JSON.stringify(app.routes.routes)

Comment: Only works for Express 3.x, not 4.x. In 4.x, you should check `app._router.stack`

Comment: This did not work as expected for me.  app._router doesn't seem to include routes from app.use('/path', otherRouter);

Comment: Is there some way that this could be integrated with a command-line script that would pull in exactly the same route files that the live app does without actually starting a web app?

Comment: At least in express 4.13.1 `app._router.stack` is undefined.

Comment: app.router.stack for express 5

Comment: With my tests in Express 4.13.4 `app._router.stack` seems to be defined (again?)

Comment: The OP wanted the HTTP methods (GET or POST). Where are those HTTP methods in the stack object? I only see the paths (at `stack[0].route.path`).

Comment: Pls edit your answer to add a way to get the methods. For example, this works for me: `router.stack.forEach(l => console.log(l.route.path, l.route.methods))`

Comment: I am wiriting a test case and want all routes to be displayed. I am importing the app file and then in that I am trying to get the app._router.stack. But it says _router does not exist on type app. I am using express 4.15.3.

Comment: Commented because I am finding many others are still looking for solution. If you are still looking for solution(one env var), you might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express/55589657#55589657

Answer (score 73):

```
app._router.stack.forEach(function(r){
  if (r.route && r.route.path){
    console.log(r.route.path)
  }
})
```

Comment: Note that if you are using something like Express Router (or other middleware) you should see @Caleb slightly longer answer that expands on this approach.

Comment: Bit shorter `app._router.stack.map( r => r.route?.path )`

Answer (score 66):

Hacky copy/paste answer courtesy of [Doug Wilson](https://github.com/dougwilson) on the [express github issues](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3308). Dirty but works like a charm.

```
function print (path, layer) {
  if (layer.route) {
    layer.route.stack.forEach(print.bind(null, path.concat(split(layer.route.path))))
  } else if (layer.name === 'router' && layer.handle.stack) {
    layer.handle.stack.forEach(print.bind(null, path.concat(split(layer.regexp))))
  } else if (layer.method) {
    console.log('%s /%s',
      layer.method.toUpperCase(),
      path.concat(split(layer.regexp)).filter(Boolean).join('/'))
  }
}

function split (thing) {
  if (typeof thing === 'string') {
    return thing.split('/')
  } else if (thing.fast_slash) {
    return ''
  } else {
    var match = thing.toString()
      .replace('\\/?', '')
      .replace('(?=\\/|$)', '$')
      .match(/^\/\^((?:\\[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\\/]|[^.*+?^${}()|[\]\\\/])*)\$\//)
    return match
      ? match[1].replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1').split('/')
      : '<complex:' + thing.toString() + '>'
  }
}

app._router.stack.forEach(print.bind(null, []))
```

Produces

[image: screengrab]

Comment: Why are routes not distinct?

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me with Express 4.15.  None of the others gave the full path.  The only caveat is that it does not give back the default root path / - none of them do.

Comment: I don't understand why do you bind arguments to `print`?

Comment: @ZzZombo ask Doug Wilson, he wrote it. You can probably clean all this up if you want.

Comment: Works only on ^5.0.0.

Answer (score 59):

`DEBUG=express:* node index.js`

If you run your app with the above command, it will launch your app with `DEBUG` module and gives routes, plus all the middleware functions that are in use.

You can refer: [ExpressJS - Debugging](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html) and [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug).

Comment: Indeed, most useful answer. @nbsamar You might even expand it to say to use `DEBUG=express:paths` to see just the path output and not all the other debug messages. Thanks!

Comment: To get just the path output I had to use `DEBUG=express:router:route` with express 4.17.1.

Answer (score 51):

This gets routes registered directly on the app (via app.VERB) and routes that are registered as router middleware (via app.use). Express 4.11.0

```
//////////////
app.get("/foo", function(req,res){
    res.send('foo');
});

//////////////
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/bar", function(req,res,next){
    res.send('bar');
});

app.use("/",router);


//////////////
var route, routes = [];

app._router.stack.forEach(function(middleware){
    if(middleware.route){ // routes registered directly on the app
        routes.push(middleware.route);
    } else if(middleware.name === 'router'){ // router middleware 
        middleware.handle.stack.forEach(function(handler){
            route = handler.route;
            route && routes.push(route);
        });
    }
});

// routes:
// {path: "/foo", methods: {get: true}}
// {path: "/bar", methods: {get: true}}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for an example that shows how to get display routes set via middleware like the Express router.

Comment: In my case this does not work with esbuild minified build

added fix

`
const endpoints: any[] = [];
    this.app._router.stack.forEach(function (middleware: any) {
      if (middleware.route) {
        // routes registered directly on the app
        endpoints.push(middleware.route);
      } else if (middleware.handle && middleware.handle.stack) {
        // router middleware
        middleware.handle.stack.forEach(function (handler: any) {
          const route = handler.route;
          route && endpoints.push(route);
        });
      }
    });`

Comment: But what will happen when `app.use("/foo",router);` ? the path of handler.route its only sub match.

Answer (score 44):

Here's a little thing I use just to get the registered paths in express 4.x

```
app._router.stack          // registered routes
  .filter(r => r.route)    // take out all the middleware
  .map(r => r.route.path)  // get all the paths
```

Comment: console.log(server._router.stack.map(r=>r.route).filter(r=>r).map(r=>`${Object.keys(r.methods).join(', ')} ${r.path}`))

Comment: where do you put this, in app.js??

Comment: @Juan inside the `app.listen` callback

Comment: I can only get  an useless result using this: `[ '*' ]`

Answer (score 36):

I have adapted an old post that is no longer online for my needs.
I've used express.Router() and registered my routes like this:

```
var questionsRoute = require('./BE/routes/questions');
app.use('/api/questions', questionsRoute);
```

I renamed the document.js file in apiTable.js and adapted it like this:

```
module.exports =  function (baseUrl, routes) {
    var Table = require('cli-table');
    var table = new Table({ head: ["", "Path"] });
    console.log('\nAPI for ' + baseUrl);
    console.log('\n********************************************');

    for (var key in routes) {
        if (routes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var val = routes[key];
            if(val.route) {
                val = val.route;
                var _o = {};
                _o[val.stack[0].method]  = [baseUrl + val.path];    
                table.push(_o);
            }       
        }
    }

    console.log(table.toString());
    return table;
};
```

then i call it in my server.js like this:

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function () {
    require('./BE/utils/apiTable')('/api/questions', questionsRoute.stack);
});
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Result example]

It's just an example but might be of use.. i hope..

Comment: This does not work for nested routes as identified here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260818/rest-with-express-js-nested-router

Comment: Beware of the link in this answer! It redirected me to a random website and forced a download to my computer.

Answer (score 30):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints works pretty well.

**Example**

Usage:

```
const all_routes = require('express-list-endpoints');
console.log(all_routes(app));
```

Output:

```
[ { path: '*', methods: [ 'OPTIONS' ] },
  { path: '/', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
  { path: '/sessions', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
  { path: '/sessions', methods: [ 'DELETE' ] },
  { path: '/users', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
  { path: '/users', methods: [ 'POST' ] } ]
```

Comment: This doesn't work with:

`server = express(); app1 = express(); server.use('/app1', app1); ...`

Answer (score 24):

### json output

```
function availableRoutes() {
  return app._router.stack
    .filter(r => r.route)
    .map(r => {
      return {
        method: Object.keys(r.route.methods)[0].toUpperCase(),
        path: r.route.path
      };
    });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(availableRoutes(), null, 2));
```

looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/api/todos"
  },
  {
    "method": "POST",
    "path": "/api/todos"
  },
  {
    "method": "PUT",
    "path": "/api/todos/:id"
  },
  {
    "method": "DELETE",
    "path": "/api/todos/:id"
  }
]
```

### string output

```
function availableRoutesString() {
  return app._router.stack
    .filter(r => r.route)
    .map(r => Object.keys(r.route.methods)[0].toUpperCase().padEnd(7) + r.route.path)
    .join("\n")
}

console.log(availableRoutesString());
```

looks like this:

```
GET    /api/todos  
POST   /api/todos  
PUT    /api/todos/:id  
DELETE /api/todos/:id
```

these are based on [@corvid's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35089029/8472592) answer

hope this helps

Comment: this doesn't show nested routes - only the top level routes

Answer (score 12):

You can implement a `/get-all-routes` API:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/get-all-routes", (req, res) => {  
  let get = app._router.stack.filter(r => r.route && r.route.methods.get).map(r => r.route.path);
  let post = app._router.stack.filter(r => r.route && r.route.methods.post).map(r => r.route.path);
  res.send({ get: get, post: post });
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

Here is a demo: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/get-all-routes-in-nodejs

Comment: Does not work for sub-routes, by example `app.use('/module', anotherRouters)`

Answer (score 10):

A function to log all routes in express 4 (can be easily tweaked for v3~)

```
function space(x) {
    var res = '';
    while(x--) res += ' ';
    return res;
}

function listRoutes(){
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length;  i++) {
        if(arguments[i].stack instanceof Array){
            console.log('');
            arguments[i].stack.forEach(function(a){
                var route = a.route;
                if(route){
                    route.stack.forEach(function(r){
                        var method = r.method.toUpperCase();
                        console.log(method,space(8 - method.length),route.path);
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

listRoutes(router, routerAuth, routerHTML);
```

Logs output:

```
GET       /isAlive
POST      /test/email
POST      /user/verify

PUT       /login
POST      /login
GET       /player
PUT       /player
GET       /player/:id
GET       /players
GET       /system
POST      /user
GET       /user
PUT       /user
DELETE    /user

GET       /
GET       /login
```

**Made this into a NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-routes**

Comment: This did not work as expected for me.  app._router doesn't seem to include routes from app.use('/path', otherRouter);

Comment: @MichaelCole Did you look at the answer below from Golo Roden?

Comment: @Dazzler13 I played with this for an hour, and wasn't able to get it to work.  Express 4.0. Made app, made router, app.use(path,router), router routes didn't appear in app._router.  Example?

Comment: The example from @Caleb below works well for routes handled with something like express.Router if that's your issue. Note that routes set with middleware (including express.Router) may not show up right away and you may need to add in a short delay before checking for them in app._router (even using the approach from @Caleb).

Comment: Can you make it render as an HTML file? That'll be interesting

Comment: @olawalejuwonm npm express-list-routes now returns array of routes you can use to render html

Comment: @Labithiotishow do i get that?

Comment: You could do this:
```js
const routes = expressListRoutes(app);
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
res.send(`<table><tbody>${routes.map(route => `<tr><td><strong>${route.method}</strong></td><td>${route.path}</td></tr>}</li>`)}</tbody></table>`);
```

Comment: Thank you @Labithiotis using the library doesn't return only empty array but express-list-endpoints works

Answer (score 9):

**Within your app at `/routes` display your express route names**

```
app.get('/routes', (req, res) => {
    res.send(app._router.stack
        .filter(r => r.route) 
        .map(r => r.route.path))
})
```

http://localhost:3000/routes

Answer (score 8):

I was inspired by Labithiotis's express-list-routes, but I wanted an overview of all my routes and brute urls in one go, and not specify a router, and figure out the prefix each time. Something I came up with was to simply replace the app.use function with my own function which stores the baseUrl and given router. From there I can print any table of all my routes.

NOTE this works for me because I declare my routes in a specific routes file (function) which gets passed in the app object, like this:

```
// index.js
[...]
var app = Express();
require(./config/routes)(app);

// ./config/routes.js
module.exports = function(app) {
    // Some static routes
    app.use('/users', [middleware], UsersRouter);
    app.use('/users/:user_id/items', [middleware], ItemsRouter);
    app.use('/otherResource', [middleware], OtherResourceRouter);
}
```

This allows me to pass in another 'app' object with a fake use function, and I can get ALL the routes. This works for me (removed some error checking for clarity, but still works for the example):

```
// In printRoutes.js (or a gulp task, or whatever)
var Express = require('express')
  , app     = Express()
  , _       = require('lodash')

// Global array to store all relevant args of calls to app.use
var APP_USED = []

// Replace the `use` function to store the routers and the urls they operate on
app.use = function() {
  var urlBase = arguments[0];

  // Find the router in the args list
  _.forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
    if (arg.name == 'router') {
      APP_USED.push({
        urlBase: urlBase,
        router: arg
      });
    }
  });
};

// Let the routes function run with the stubbed app object.
require('./config/routes')(app);

// GRAB all the routes from our saved routers:
_.each(APP_USED, function(used) {
  // On each route of the router
  _.each(used.router.stack, function(stackElement) {
    if (stackElement.route) {
      var path = stackElement.route.path;
      var method = stackElement.route.stack[0].method.toUpperCase();

      // Do whatever you want with the data. I like to make a nice table :)
      console.log(method + " -> " + used.urlBase + path);
    }
  });
});
```

This full example (with some basic CRUD routers) was just tested and printed out:

```
GET -> /users/users
GET -> /users/users/:user_id
POST -> /users/users
DELETE -> /users/users/:user_id
GET -> /users/:user_id/items/
GET -> /users/:user_id/items/:item_id
PUT -> /users/:user_id/items/:item_id
POST -> /users/:user_id/items/
DELETE -> /users/:user_id/items/:item_id
GET -> /otherResource/
GET -> /otherResource/:other_resource_id
POST -> /otherResource/
DELETE -> /otherResource/:other_resource_id
```

Using [cli-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-table) I got something like this:

```
┌────────┬───────────────────────┐
│        │ => Users              │
├────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ GET    │ /users/users          │
├────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ GET    │ /users/users/:user_id │
├────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ POST   │ /users/users          │
├────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ DELETE │ /users/users/:user_id │
└────────┴───────────────────────┘
┌────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│        │ => Items                       │
├────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ GET    │ /users/:user_id/items/         │
├────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ GET    │ /users/:user_id/items/:item_id │
├────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ PUT    │ /users/:user_id/items/:item_id │
├────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ POST   │ /users/:user_id/items/         │
├────────┼────────────────────────────────┤
│ DELETE │ /users/:user_id/items/:item_id │
└────────┴────────────────────────────────┘
┌────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│        │ => OtherResources                 │
├────────┼───────────────────────────────────┤
│ GET    │ /otherResource/                   │
├────────┼───────────────────────────────────┤
│ GET    │ /otherResource/:other_resource_id │
├────────┼───────────────────────────────────┤
│ POST   │ /otherResource/                   │
├────────┼───────────────────────────────────┤
│ DELETE │ /otherResource/:other_resource_id │
└────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Which kicks ass.

Answer (score 5):

### Express 4

Given an **Express 4** configuration with endpoints and nested routers

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()

app.get(...)
app.post(...)

router.use(...)
router.get(...)
router.post(...)

app.use(router)
```

Expanding the [@caleb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28199817/1750243) answer it is possible to obtain all routes recursively and sorted.

```
getRoutes(app._router && app._router.stack)
// =>
// [
//     [ 'GET', '/'], 
//     [ 'POST', '/auth'],
//     ...
// ]

/**
* Converts Express 4 app routes to an array representation suitable for easy parsing.
* @arg {Array} stack An Express 4 application middleware list.
* @returns {Array} An array representation of the routes in the form [ [ 'GET', '/path' ], ... ].
*/
function getRoutes(stack) {
        const routes = (stack || [])
                // We are interested only in endpoints and router middleware.
                .filter(it => it.route || it.name === 'router')
                // The magic recursive conversion.
                .reduce((result, it) => {
                        if (! it.route) {
                                // We are handling a router middleware.
                                const stack = it.handle.stack
                                const routes = getRoutes(stack)

                                return result.concat(routes)
                        }

                        // We are handling an endpoint.
                        const methods = it.route.methods
                        const path = it.route.path

                        const routes = Object
                                .keys(methods)
                                .map(m => [ m.toUpperCase(), path ])

                        return result.concat(routes)
                }, [])
                // We sort the data structure by route path.
                .sort((prev, next) => {
                        const [ prevMethod, prevPath ] = prev
                        const [ nextMethod, nextPath ] = next

                        if (prevPath < nextPath) {
                                return -1
                        }

                        if (prevPath > nextPath) {
                                return 1
                        }

                        return 0
                })

        return routes
}
```

---

For basic string output.

```
infoAboutRoutes(app)
```

[image: Console output]

```
/**
* Converts Express 4 app routes to a string representation suitable for console output.
* @arg {Object} app An Express 4 application
* @returns {string} A string representation of the routes.
*/
function infoAboutRoutes(app) {
        const entryPoint = app._router && app._router.stack
        const routes = getRoutes(entryPoint)

        const info = routes
                .reduce((result, it) => {
                        const [ method, path ] = it

                        return result + `${method.padEnd(6)} ${path}\n`
                }, '')

        return info
}
```

---

#### Update 1:

Due to the internal limitations of Express 4 it is not possible to retrieve mounted app and mounted routers. For example it is not possible to obtain routes from this configuration.

```
const subApp = express()
app.use('/sub/app', subApp)

const subRouter = express.Router()
app.use('/sub/route', subRouter)
```

Comment: Listing mounted routes works with this package: https://github.com/AlbertoFdzM/express-list-endpoints

Answer (score 4):

Need some adjusts but should work for Express v4. Including those routes added with `.use()`.

```
function listRoutes(routes, stack, parent){

  parent = parent || '';
  if(stack){
    stack.forEach(function(r){
      if (r.route && r.route.path){
        var method = '';

        for(method in r.route.methods){
          if(r.route.methods[method]){
            routes.push({method: method.toUpperCase(), path: parent + r.route.path});
          }
        }       

      } else if (r.handle && r.handle.name == 'router') {
        const routerName = r.regexp.source.replace("^\\","").replace("\\/?(?=\\/|$)","");
        return listRoutes(routes, r.handle.stack, parent + routerName);
      }
    });
    return routes;
  } else {
    return listRoutes([], app._router.stack);
  }
}

//Usage on app.js
const routes = listRoutes(); //array: ["method: path", "..."]
```

edit: code improvements

Answer (score 3):

Slightly updated and more functional approach to @prranay's answer:

```
const routes = app._router.stack
    .filter((middleware) => middleware.route)
    .map((middleware) => `${Object.keys(middleware.route.methods).join(', ')} -> ${middleware.route.path}`)

console.log(JSON.stringify(routes, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 3):

**Initialize express router**

```
let router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
        status: `API Its Working`,
        route: router.stack.filter(r => r.route)
           .map(r=> { return {"path":r.route.path, 
 "methods":r.route.methods}}),
        message: 'Welcome to my crafted with love!',
      });
   });
```

*Import user controller*

```
var userController = require('./controller/userController');
```

*User routes*

```
router.route('/users')
   .get(userController.index)
   .post(userController.new);
router.route('/users/:user_id')
   .get(userController.view)
   .patch(userController.update)
   .put(userController.update)
   .delete(userController.delete);
```

*Export API routes*

```
module.exports = router;
```

**Output**

```
{"status":"API Its Working, APP Route","route": 
[{"path":"/","methods":{"get":true}}, 
{"path":"/users","methods":{"get":true,"post":true}}, 
{"path":"/users/:user_id","methods": ....}
```

Answer (score 3):

All of these seem overly complex.
On `"express": "^4.18.1"`

```
const routes: { methods: string[], path: string }[] = [];

const parseRoute = (def) => {
  if (def.route) {
    routes.push({ path: def.route.path, methods: Object.keys(def.route.methods) });
  } else if (def.name === 'router') {
    // nested route (sub router)..
    def.handle.stack.forEach(parseRoute);
  }
}

// loop over and parse routes
app._router.stack.forEach(parseRoute);

console.log(routes);
//{ path: '/', methods: [ 'get' ] },
//{ path: '/healthcheck', methods: [ 'get' ] },
//{ path: '/assets/theme.css', methods: [ 'get' ] },
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
let routes = []
app._router.stack.forEach(function (middleware) {
    if(middleware.route) {
        routes.push(Object.keys(middleware.route.methods) + " -> " + middleware.route.path);
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(routes, null, 4));
```

O/P:

```
[
    "get -> /posts/:id",
    "post -> /posts",
    "patch -> /posts"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

in all server this is how i do it

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('home')
})
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    console.log('/home')
})

function list(id) {
    const path = require('path');

    const defaultOptions = {
        prefix: '',
        spacer: 7,
    };

    const COLORS = {
        yellow: 33,
        green: 32,
        blue: 34,
        red: 31,
        grey: 90,
        magenta: 35,
        clear: 39,
    };

    const spacer = (x) => (x > 0 ? [...new Array(x)].map(() => ' ').join('') : '');

    const colorText = (color, string) => `\u001b[${color}m${string}\u001b[${COLORS.clear}m`;

    function colorMethod(method) {
        switch (method) {
            case 'POST':
                return colorText(COLORS.yellow, method);
            case 'GET':
                return colorText(COLORS.green, method);
            case 'PUT':
                return colorText(COLORS.blue, method);
            case 'DELETE':
                return colorText(COLORS.red, method);
            case 'PATCH':
                return colorText(COLORS.grey, method);
            default:
                return method;
        }
    }

    function getPathFromRegex(regexp) {
        return regexp.toString().replace('/^', '').replace('?(?=\\/|$)/i', '').replace(/\\\//g, '/');
    }

    function combineStacks(acc, stack) {
        if (stack.handle.stack) {
            const routerPath = getPathFromRegex(stack.regexp);
            return [...acc, ...stack.handle.stack.map((stack) => ({ routerPath, ...stack }))];
        }
        return [...acc, stack];
    }

    function getStacks(app) {
        // Express 3
        if (app.routes) {
            // convert to express 4
            return Object.keys(app.routes)
                .reduce((acc, method) => [...acc, ...app.routes[method]], [])
                .map((route) => ({ route: { stack: [route] } }));
        }

        // Express 4
        if (app._router && app._router.stack) {
            return app._router.stack.reduce(combineStacks, []);
        }

        // Express 4 Router
        if (app.stack) {
            return app.stack.reduce(combineStacks, []);
        }

        // Express 5
        if (app.router && app.router.stack) {
            return app.router.stack.reduce(combineStacks, []);
        }

        return [];
    }

    function expressListRoutes(app, opts) {
        const stacks = getStacks(app);
        const options = {...defaultOptions, ...opts };

        if (stacks) {
            for (const stack of stacks) {
                if (stack.route) {
                    const routeLogged = {};
                    for (const route of stack.route.stack) {
                        const method = route.method ? route.method.toUpperCase() : null;
                        if (!routeLogged[method] && method) {
                            const stackMethod = colorMethod(method);
                            const stackSpace = spacer(options.spacer - method.length);
                            const stackPath = path.resolve(
                                [options.prefix, stack.routerPath, stack.route.path, route.path].filter((s) => !!s).join(''),
                            );
                            console.info(stackMethod, stackSpace, stackPath);
                            routeLogged[method] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };

    expressListRoutes(app)
}

list(1);
```

if you run it then this will happen

GET      C:
GET      C:\home

Answer (score 1):

On Express 3.5.x, I add this before starting the app to print the routes on my terminal :

```
var routes = app.routes;
for (var verb in routes){
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(verb)) {
      routes[verb].forEach(function(route){
        console.log(verb + " : "+route['path']);
      });
    }
}
```

Maybe it can help...

Answer (score 1):

For express 4.x

Here's a gross 1 liner that works with routes added to `app` and routes added to `express.Router()`.

It returns this structure.

```js
[
    {
        "path": "/api",
        "methods": {
            "get": true
        }
    },
    {
        "path": "/api/servermembers/",
        "methods": {
            "get": true
        }
    },
    {
        "path": "/api/servermembers/find/:query",
        "methods": {
            "get": true
        }
    }
]
```

Modules that use `express.Router()` would need to export like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  router,
  path: "/servermembers",
};
```

And be added like this:

```js
app.use(`/api${ServerMemberRoutes.path}`, ServerMemberRoutes.router);
```

```js
app.get(
  "/api",
  /**
   * Gets the API's available routes.
   * @param {request} _req
   * @param {response} res
   */
  (_req, res) => {
    res.json(
      [app._router, ServerMemberRoutes]
        .map((routeInfo) => ({
          entityPath: routeInfo.path || "",
          stack: (routeInfo?.router?.stack || routeInfo.stack).filter(
            (stack) => stack.route
          ),
        }))
        .map(({ entityPath, stack }) =>
          stack.map(({ route: { path, methods } }) => ({
            path: entityPath ? `/api${entityPath}${path}` : path,
            methods,
          }))
        ).flat()
    );
  }
);
```

Of course, the `/api` base url prefix could be stored in a variable as well if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple method to get the routes:

First, create a interface to mount the route object:

```js
interface Route {
    path: string;
    method: string;
    prefix?: string;
}
```

So, iterate over express routes

```js
public getRoutes() {
        const routes: Route[] = []
        this.app._router.stack.map((r: any) => {
            if (r.name === 'router') {
                const prefix =  r.regexp.toString().replace(/\/\^|\/\?|\/\$/g, '').replace('(?=\\/|$)', '').replace(/\\(.)/g, '$1').replace(/\/i\n/g, '').replace(/\/i$/, '');
                r.handle.stack?.map((r: any) => {
                    const path = r.route?.path;
                    r.route?.stack?.map((r: any) => {
                        routes.push({
                            path: path,
                            method: r.method,
                            prefix: prefix
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        })

        return routes;
    }
```

Output:

```
[
  { path: '/', method: 'get', prefix: '' },
  { path: '/2', method: 'get', prefix: '' },
  { path: '/users', method: 'get', prefix: '/api' },
  { path: '/user', method: 'post', prefix: '/api' },
  { path: '/user/:id', method: 'delete', prefix: '/api' }
]
```

Comment: actually, fail to work with complex nested routes.

Answer (score 1):

typescript / express 4+

**pakages:**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express-list-endpoints
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints

**install:**

```
npm i --save-dev @types/express-list-endpoints
npm i --save npm i express-list-endpoints
```

**Example List Route Controller:**

```
import listEndpoints from 'express-list-endpoints';
import { Express, Request, Response } from 'express';

export class MyController {

    public async listRoutes(_req: Request, res: Response  ): Promise<void> {
       const app:Express = res.app as unknown as Express;
       res.status(200).json( {result: listEndpoints(app)}  );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was looking at all the answers.. didn't like most.. took some from a few.. made this:

```
const resolveRoutes = (stack) => {
  return stack.map(function (layer) {
    if (layer.route && layer.route.path.isString()) {
      let methods = Object.keys(layer.route.methods);
      if (methods.length > 20)
        methods = ["ALL"];

      return {methods: methods, path: layer.route.path};
    }

    if (layer.name === 'router')  // router middleware
      return resolveRoutes(layer.handle.stack);

  }).filter(route => route);
};

const routes = resolveRoutes(express._router.stack);
const printRoute = (route) => {
  if (Array.isArray(route))
    return route.forEach(route => printRoute(route));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(route.methods) + " " + route.path);
};

printRoute(routes);
```

not the prettiest.. but nested, and does the trick

also note the 20 there... I just assume there will not be a normal route with 20 methods.. so I deduce it is all..

Answer (score 0):

route details are listing route for "express": "4.x.x",

```
import {
  Router
} from 'express';
var router = Router();

router.get("/routes", (req, res, next) => {
  var routes = [];
  var i = 0;
  router.stack.forEach(function (r) {
    if (r.route && r.route.path) {
      r.route.stack.forEach(function (type) {
        var method = type.method.toUpperCase();
        routes[i++] = {
          no:i,
          method: method.toUpperCase(),
          path: r.route.path
        };
      })
    }
  })

  res.send('<h1>List of routes.</h1>' + JSON.stringify(routes));
});
```

SIMPLE OUTPUT OF CODE

```
List of routes.

[
{"no":1,"method":"POST","path":"/admin"},
{"no":2,"method":"GET","path":"/"},
{"no":3,"method":"GET","path":"/routes"},
{"no":4,"method":"POST","path":"/student/:studentId/course/:courseId/topic/:topicId/task/:taskId/item"},
{"no":5,"method":"GET","path":"/student/:studentId/course/:courseId/topic/:topicId/task/:taskId/item"},
{"no":6,"method":"PUT","path":"/student/:studentId/course/:courseId/topic/:topicId/task/:taskId/item/:itemId"},
{"no":7,"method":"DELETE","path":"/student/:studentId/course/:courseId/topic/:topicId/task/:taskId/item/:itemId"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this npm package, it will give the web-output as well as terminal output in nice formatted table view.

[image]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-routes-catalogue

Comment: This other package have ton more acceptance. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints . I'ts 21.111 against 34 weekly downloads. However, `express-routes-catalogue` also displays the routes as HTML, ehile the other one doesn't.

Comment: not bad, the documentation of package differs from the actual package name when requiring and this package like all the other mentioned only show single layer routes where it is included

Comment: @hamzakhan p.s thanks for the update.I'm the author, soon will be updated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Static code analysis approach.

This tool analyzes source code and shows routing info without starting a server.

```
npx express-router-dependency-graph --rootDir=path/to/project
# json or markdown output
```

https://github.com/azu/express-router-dependency-graph

Example output:

| File | Method | Routing | Middlewares | FilePath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| user/index.ts |  |  |  |  |
|  | get | /getUserById | requireView | user/index.ts#L1-3 |
|  | get | /getUserList | requireView | user/index.ts#L4-6 |
|  | post | /updateUserById | requireEdit | user/index.ts#L8-10 |
|  | post | /deleteUserById | requireEdit | user/index.ts#L12-20 |
| game/index.ts |  |  |  |  |
|  | get | /getGameList | requireView | game/index.ts#L1-3 |
|  | get | /getGameById | requireView | game/index.ts#L4-6 |
|  | post | /updateGameById | requireEdit | game/index.ts#L8-10 |
|  | post | /deleteGameById | requireEdit | game/index.ts#L12-20 |

Comment: Great solution! Alas did not produce any useful results for https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost But it did find a few routes in the `node_modules`!

Answer (score 0):

I recently was struggling with finding a tool that could do this well. Every solution/existing npm package I found had corner cases where it failed, and my project had those corner cases. I also wanted an output I could use for my project as well.

So I built my own tool: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-route-parser

It also allows you to attach arbitrary meta-data to a route via a middleware. This can be used in a variety of ways, such as attaching schema's to your routes.

Check it out and see if it helps

Comment: Can you please make it render as an HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, it is apparently not possible to output mounted routes just like that. To get around this problem, I wrote my own function that registers the routes for me and in which I add the routes to an array:

```
let registeredRoutes = [];

/**
 * Utility function for registering routes.
 *
 *
 * @param route The route to add.
 * @param route.basePath The basePath of the route.
 * @param route.path The path of the route.
 * @param route.name The name of the route.
 * @param route.caption The caption of the route.
 * @param route.description The description of the route.
 * @param router The router to add the route to.
 * @param fn The function to call
 */
export function registerRoute(route, router, fn) {
    if (route.path.startsWith("/")) {
        throw new Error(`(${route.path}) => route.path should not start with '/'.`);
    }

    const path = route.path.endsWith("/") ? route.path.slice(0, -1) : route.path;
    const fullPath =
        route.path === "" ? route.basePath : `${route.basePath}/${path}`;

    router.get(path, fn);
    registeredRoutes.push({
        ...route,
        fullPath,
    });
    return router;
}

export function getRoutes() {
    return registeredRoutes;
}
```

I call this method like this in my `index.route.ts`:

```
const router = express();

registerRoute(
    {
        basePath: "/",
        path: "",
        name: "MY_TECHNICAL_NAME",
        caption: "The caption of the route",
        description: "Some description",
    },
    router,
    (req, res) => req.send("Hello World!"),
);
```

And create an endpoint for getting every route like this:

```
router.get(
  "/routes",
  (req, res) => req.send(getRoutes()),
);
```

It's not perfect, but it seems to do the job quite good.

Answer (score -1):

In express 4.*

```
//Obtiene las rutas declaradas de la API
    let listPathRoutes: any[] = [];
    let rutasRouter = _.filter(application._router.stack, rutaTmp => rutaTmp.name === 'router');
    rutasRouter.forEach((pathRoute: any) => {
        let pathPrincipal = pathRoute.regexp.toString();
        pathPrincipal = pathPrincipal.replace('/^\\','');
        pathPrincipal = pathPrincipal.replace('?(?=\\/|$)/i','');
        pathPrincipal = pathPrincipal.replace(/\\\//g,'/');
        let routesTemp = _.filter(pathRoute.handle.stack, rutasTmp => rutasTmp.route !== undefined);
        routesTemp.forEach((route: any) => {
            let pathRuta = `${pathPrincipal.replace(/\/\//g,'')}${route.route.path}`;
            let ruta = {
                path: pathRuta.replace('//','/'),
                methods: route.route.methods
            }
            listPathRoutes.push(ruta);
        });
    });console.log(listPathRoutes)
```

Answer (score -1):

This one worked for me

```js
// Express 4.x
function getRoutes(stacks: any, routes: { path: string; method: string }[] = [], prefix: string = ''): { path: string; method: string }[] {
  for (const stack of stacks) {
    if (stack.route) {
      routes.push({ path: `${prefix}${stack.route.path}`, method: stack.route.stack[0].method });
    }
    if (stack && stack.handle && stack.handle.stack) {
      let stackPrefix = stack.regexp.source.match(/\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/g);

      if (stackPrefix) {
        stackPrefix = prefix + stackPrefix.join('');
      }

      routes.concat(getRoutes(stack.handle.stack, routes, stackPrefix));
    }
  }
  return routes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const routes = {}
function routerRecursion(middleware, pointer, currentName) {
  if (middleware.route) { // routes registered directly on the app
    if (!Array.isArray(pointer['routes'])) {
      pointer['routes'] = []
    }
    const routeObj = {
      path: middleware.route.path,
      method: middleware.route.stack[0].method
    }
    pointer['routes'].push(routeObj)
  } else if (middleware.name === 'router') { // inside router
    const current = middleware.regexp.toString().replace(/\/\^\\\//, '').replace(/\\\/\?\(\?\=\\\/\|\$\)\/\i/, '')
    pointer[current] = {}
    middleware.handle.stack.forEach(function (handler) {
      routerRecursion(handler, pointer[current], current)
    });
  }
}
app._router.stack.forEach(function (middleware) {
  routerRecursion(middleware, routes, 'main')
});
console.log(routes);
```

app._router.stack.forEach(function (middleware) {
routerRecursion(middleware, routes, 'main')
});
console.log(routes);

Answer (score -2):

I published a package that prints all middleware as well as routes, really useful when trying to audit an express application. You mount the package as middleware, so it even prints out itself:

https://github.com/ErisDS/middleware-stack-printer

It prints a kind of tree like:

```
- middleware 1
- middleware 2
- Route /thing/
- - middleware 3
- - controller (HTTP VERB)
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a one-line function to pretty-print the routes in an Express `app`:

```
const getAppRoutes = (app) => app._router.stack.reduce(
  (acc, val) => acc.concat(
    val.route ? [val.route.path] :
      val.name === "router" ? val.handle.stack.filter(
        x => x.route).map(
          x => val.regexp.toString().match(/\/[a-z]+/)[0] + (
            x.route.path === '/' ? '' : x.route.path)) : []) , []).sort();
```