# How can I obtain matched route pattern in express JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I want my logger middleware to log each matched route when response is sent. But there may be any number of nested subroutes. Let's suppose I have this:

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(function myLogger(req, res, next)
{
    res.send = function()
    {
        //Here I want to get matched route like this: '/router/smth/:id'
        //How can I do this?
    });
}

app.use('/router', router);

router.get('/smth/:id', function(req, res, next)
{
  res.send(response);
});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No, I need matched URL pattern with that ':id' part and not exact URL itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because app-level middleware has no knowledge of routes, this is impossible. However, if you use your logger middleware as route middleware like:

```
router.get('/smith/:id', logger, function (req, res) { ... });
```

You can use a combination of two parameters on the request object:

```
req.route.path => '/smth/:id'
req.originalUrl => '/router/smth/123'
```

I'll leave it up to you how you want to combine both into one string.

Comment: Looks like that `req.route` is not supported anymore. How can I do that in the recent versions of `express`?

Comment: @Nawaz `req.route` is supported in [5.x (most recent)](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.route), [4.x](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.route) and [3.x](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.route)

Comment: ah, yes. I'm new to express, so I was trying to `console.log(req.route)` at the app-level middleware, where it is printing `undefined`. However, when I did the same in the router-level middleware, it prints what your links show. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

**Here's the code (in express 2.x)**

```js
// npm -v express       
// 2.14.2
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var routes = app.routes; // See Reference 1.

  for(var method in routes) {
    if(routes.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
      for(var route in routes[method]) {
        if(req.url.toString().match(routes[method][route].regexp)) {
          console.log('Route Debugger: ' + routes[method][route].path);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/router', router);

router.get('/smth/:id', function(req, res, next)
{
  res.send(response);
});
```

**What does this do?**

1. It queries the `app.routes` object. Now we have access to all the routes defined in our application.
2. We match the current url `req.url` with the regular expression of each route.
3. Since this is a application level middleware, it runs for every request. So you get logging like `Route Debugger: /router/smth/:id`, if you hit a url like `/router/smith/123`

**Reference 1** : http://thejackalofjavascript.com/list-all-rest-endpoints/
**Reference 2** : [How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express)

Comment: You should also add that this performs an O(n^2) blocking lookup on each request and duplicates what Express is doing under the covers for route matching. Not bad for a small order of routes, but for larger applications this is a huge bottleneck as compared to O(1) lookup at the route level.