# How to list all paths in an Express application using Node.js, like "rake routes" command in Rails Application?

Tags: node.js, express

I've attempted to install several NPM packages into my express app that allow me to view my apps routes but I haven't had any success.  I'm used to using `rake routes` to display my routes in my rails applications but haven't found anything similar in express.  What are the best ways to get a similar functionality in express?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into npm package [pathfinder-ui](https://github.com/smlee/pathfinder-ui)? I'm not a Rails user, but I believe it's  similar to `rake routes` in the sense that it'll display all  registered routes in an Express (4.x) app. It's also distinct in that:

- it's a GUI that lets you view all your routes as either 1.) a table that can be filtered/searched, or 2.) an expandable tree diagram
- lets you test your routes with a request builder -
  an alternative to curl (kind of like using POSTMAN if you've ever worked
  with it).

It might be offering more than what you're looking for, but it should definitely display your Express routes in a dev-friendly manner and is pretty easy to configure.

I also just came across this package that might be worth a look as well: [express-ls-routes](https://github.com/jaketrent/express-ls-routes).

Answer (score 1):

You can run,

```
npm install express-route-list-cli
```

and then

```
npx route-list <relative app file path>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can find another stack overflow question with same context** of listing all paths/routes in an Express application in the given bellow post:

[How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express)

For a reference you can also visit the following thread regarding ["List All REST Endpoints built using Express or Restify"](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/list-all-rest-endpoints/)

**Once if you successfully follow the last given link you will get the out put path/rout listed like bellow in the image:**

[image]

Comment: @Katgus:  If you got another solution please post it here, that may help many other.

Answer (score 0):

i created this code by reading above answers. this will not only return direct routes, but also routes created via router on specific path:

```js
const app = express()

let allRouters=[
    ["/api/v1/auth",AuthRouter],
    ["/api/v1/user",UserRouter]
]

app
    .use(express.json())
    .use(cookieParser())

allRouters.forEach(it=>app.use(it[0],it[1]))
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server started at port 3000"))

app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    let routes = [
        ["/",app._router],
        ...allRouters
    ]
    let routesJs = {}
    routes.forEach(it=>{
        let key = it[0]
        let value  = it[1].stack.filter(r => r.route).map(r => ({method: Object.keys(r.route.methods)[0].toUpperCase(), path: r.route.path}));
        routesJs[key]=value
    })
       res.json(routesJs)
} )
```

the response for `localhost:3000/` looked something like this:

```json
{
    "/": [
        { "method": "GET","path": "/" },
        { "method": "GET","path": "/mail"}
    ],
    "/api/v1/auth": [
        {"method": "POST","path": "/signup"},
        {"method": "POST","path": "/login"},
        {"method": "POST","path": "/securelogin"},
        {"method": "PATCH","path": "/forgotpassword"},
        {"method": "PATCH","path": "/resetpassword"}
    ],
    "/api/v1/user": [
        {"method": "PATCH","path": "/updateprofile"},
        {"method": "GET","path": "/allusers"}
    ]
}
```