# Set Name for Routes and Return All Routes with Name in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, I have these routes:

```
router.get('/addUser',name="addUser");
router.post('/editUser',name="editUser");
```

Now I want set `Name` for these routes and Return All Routes With Name:

```
- Add User
- Edit User
```

How can I set a `Name` for each route and return all routes with `Name` in nodejs?

Comment: did you want something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/named-routes

Comment: @user9879287 i dint want to use the npm-package . iwant write code fir this

Comment: can you give an idea how you want to use the names?

Comment: If you don't want to use an additional package, you'd have to handle naming and searching yourself. To actually get a list of routes associated with an app, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express

Comment: @Ouroborus i want to retrun all routes with name in for example return name . this link can not set the name

Comment: Yes, that's why you'd have to manage naming and querying against them yourself. Routes don't have names on their own. They just have a path and a handler. (I see you're trying to set a name using a named parameter. If you're using something other than Express for routing, you should mention that.)

Comment: @Ouroborus i want return route by name for using dynamic access level .

Comment: Express routes don't have names. Are you using some other package?

Comment: @Ouroborus no i'm not . i want to find a way for using this

Comment: So you'll need to create a way to associate names with routes (possibly an object with the keys as the names and arrays of routes as the values) and then you'll need to create a way to search those names and retrieve the routes.

Comment: @Ouroborus yes . i want to create a dynamic access level .  ican find name of route and show that to use .

Comment: Then you're going to have to write some code and, if you run into problems, we can help with troubleshooting. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service.