# Express Route calling methods at initialization phase?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-router

I have a basic express app, where app.ts looks like

```
import * as express from "express";
const application: express.Application = express();
 
application.get("/", function(
  request: express.Request,
  response: express.Response
) {
  console.log("Inside Router ");
  response.json({ "test": true});
}); 

application.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("sever ready");
});
```

In this case, the console message "Inside Route" is printed in server console when the route is hit.

However,

wrapper.ts

```
const methods = () => {

};

console.log("This is a testable offence");
export const wrapperMethod = {methods};
```

```
 const express = require('express');
const wrapper = require('./wrapper');
const application = express();


application.get("/city", function(
  request,
  response
) {
  console.log("when");
  let results = {};
  let test = wrapper.methods();
  response.json(results);
}); 

application.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("sever ready");
});
```

NPM COMMAND:

```
nodemon ts-node ./src/index.ts
```

In this case, on server start, we can observe "This is a testable offence" is being printed.

But the message "Inside Route" is only printed when the route is hit.

can anyone explain the reason for the same ?

Comment: Seems like you want to use it as a middleware (?) If so, you have to call all of your middlewares before your route

Comment: shouldn't it just be `export const method;` instead of `export const method = method;`

Comment: @kmp my question is to find out, within the route there is a console statement which is printed on server start, however the console message is being printed which is inside wrapper.method on server start. I want to understand the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Hmm I tried to reproduce this, but it works for me as expected, i.e. `Inside wrapper method` is only called when the route is hit. Is this really all of your code? Is there maybe a middleware that also calls the wrapper?

Comment: @RajendrakumarVankadari can you show us your whole index.js? I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: updated the exact one I am able along with the npm script that I currently run.

Comment: The problem is, when you load `wrapper` it loads the entire file, so `console.log()` runs immediately. Put your code inside your function so it only runs when it's called. In your case, it will only run when you hit up the `"/"` route

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

1. All code inside of the module will run if we import it,
2. A callback function will run when reciprocal action occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` that prints "Inside router" is located inside a callback that is called only when the route "/" is hit. So the message is printed when the route "/" is hit.

The 2nd `console.log` is located at the top-level of the `wrapper.ts` module, so it is called only when `wrapper.ts` is loaded (at `require('./wrapper')`), which happens only when the application starts.

If you want to log that 2nd message every time `wrapper.methods`is called, you need to put that `console.log` inside `wrapper.methods`.

Answer (score 0):

TS is basically super set of javascript, so let's talk in terms of javascript.

While importing javascript, it execute the file, evaluate the script and cache it.

```
// module.ts
const app = "HELLO"

export {app}
```

```
// index.ts
import { app } from "./module.ts"

console.log(app);

app = 100; // you will get error here, because it already evaluated in module.ts
```

In your case, actually `application.get` has been executed but the callback function i.e `function (req, res)` is executed by the express whenever the particular route is hit by the user.

```
// express.ts
import { Router } from "express"

const router = Router(); // creating express router
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log("hit by ", req.ip)
  res.send("PING")
})

export default router;
```

So basically this whole code will be executed as soon as you will import the file into another

```
// server.ts
import router from "./express"
import express from "express"

// creating express application
const app = express();
// registering the route
app.use("/", router);

app.listen(3000)
```

Console after starting server

```
$ ts-node server.ts
```

Running command on terminal

```
$ curl localhost:3000
PONG
```

The server terminal after hitting api would be

```
hit by ::1
```

If you want to see all the routes registered in app, see this question [How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express)

Answer (score 0):

After you use `require`, node.js will wrap your function with this.

```
'(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
    '\n});'
```

You could try to type `node` in your terminal and type `require("module").wrapper` to see.
So, node will put your code in this function, then execute this wrapper function like following code.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    const methods = () => {

    };
    console.log("This is a testable offence");
    module.exports = {
        wrapperMethod: {
            methods
        }
    }
})
```

Note: I convert your `export` to CommonJS syntax.

After node execute this function, you could access `wrapperMethod` in outside file, and `console.log` should be printed.
We could simplify thin function like following code.

```js
(function () {
    console.log("This is a testable offence");
})
```

If you execute this function, what is it with output?
It's `console.log` message.

So, when you use `require`, node will execute the content of file with `wrapper function`.
That's why when your server startup, it display `This is a testable offence`.
Because you `require` your wrapper file with `require('./wrapper');` in the head of index file.