# List of all routes in express app (express-promise-router)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

In my backend app I am using [`express-promise-router`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router) to manage my routes.
For example:

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const router = require( 'express-promise-router' )();
let app = express();
app.use( router.get( "/hc" , ( req,res,next )=> res.status( 200 ).send( "healthy!" ) ) );
```

I want to list all the routes in the backend app.
since I am using the `express-promise-router`, I can't use the `app._router.stack`

The problem I am facing is that I used "sub-routing":

```
app.use('/api/v1', require('./router'));
```

in `router.js:`

```
router.use('/api/v1/user', require('./user_r'));
```

in `user_r.js:`

```
router.get(...)
```

all the dependencies I tried, such as `express-list-routes` and `express-list-endpoints` weren't useful because of the hierarchy.

I did though try suggestions from here:

- [How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express)
- [List All Routes in express app #3308](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3308)

Any suggestions how to get it done?

Comment: You'd need to rely on lib internals for that, and I'm not sure if it's possible to do. Probably available on router object somewhere, e.g. router.stack. What's the purpose? If you just need to know them, just find the with regex. If you need a list at runtime, write a helper that wraps around app.use( router... and keeps an array of routes.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the package [express-list-endpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints) in the past, worked great.

#### Usage:

```
const express = require("express");
const expressPromiseRouter = require("express-promise-router");
const listEndpoints = require("express-list-endpoints");

const app = express();
const router = expressPromiseRouter();

router.get("/ping", (req, res) => res.send("pong!"));

app.use(router);

console.log(listEndpoints(app));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it worked for me.
do you know how to group routes?
I use this way but it did'nt work properly
```import userRoutes from "./app/routes/userRoutes.js";
import sceneRoutes from "./app/routes/sceneRoutes.js"

app.use( "/api/users", userRoutes )
app.use( "/api/scene", sceneRoutes )```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [express-list-endpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints) module for that:

```
const listEndpoints = require('express-list-endpoints');
let app = require('express')();
// ... app usage
console.log(listEndpoints(app));
```

Also, may you already seen these, but this can be useful later:

- [How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express)
- [List All Routes in express app #3308](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3308)