# How to get all registered routes in Express, prettified?

Tags: node.js, express

I noticed that there is a very popular question, here:

[How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14934452/8297745)

And I read all the answers... The most important ones were:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14934933/8297745
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46397967/8297745

But I was not able to implement this inside my code.
It keeps giving me `TypeError` errors, `ForEach Not Found` errors.

The code I was able to produce so far, was:

```
// #### Configuração do Servidor ####
const app = express();
app.use('/auth', routes)

// Imprimir as rotas. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28199817/8297745
function printRoutes(stack) {
    stack.forEach(middleware => {
        if (middleware.route) { // Caso seja uma rota
            console.log(middleware.route);
        } else if (middleware.name === 'router') { // Caso seja um sub-roteador
            printRoutes(middleware.handle.stack);
        }
    });
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
    if (app._router && app._router.stack) {
        printRoutes(app._router.stack);
    }
});
```

But, when I tried the above code, which I managed to built thanks to some answers on that StackOverflow question, the best output I was able to achieve, without errors, was:

```
Route {
  path: '/generate',
  stack: [
    Layer {
      handle: [Function (anonymous)],
      name: '<anonymous>',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [],
      regexp: /^\/?$/i,
      method: 'get'
    }
  ],
  methods: { get: true }
}
Route {
  path: '/callback',
  stack: [
    Layer {
      handle: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
      name: '<anonymous>',
      params: undefined,
      path: undefined,
      keys: [],
      regexp: /^\/?$/i,
      method: 'get'
    }
  ],
  methods: { get: true }
}
```

Which is totally different from the one @AlienWebguy showed.

I get it - The question is 10 years old and maybe there are better and good ways to do this after such a long time. Which is exactly what I am finding hard to do...

I expect my output to be something like:

```
GET /auth/generate
GET /auth/callback
```

But the two main things that I noticed and am strugling with is:

1. Access the values `method` and `path` to mount the string.
2. My main parent route, `auth`, is not being shown...

Please.

I really tried and took a look into that question there, but I am not being able to progress further. I even asked ChatGPT, but he is getting into a loop and all his answers are crashing my app...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46397967/6463558