# How to get all the registered routes in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have a web application built using Node.js and Express. Now I would like to list all the registered routes with their appropriate methods from code written in controller.

```
-->Router [ Folder ]
   |
   |-->task.js
   |-->work.js

--> task.js
    |--> `router.post("/createUser", createUser);`
    |--> `router.post("/addTask", addTask);`
--> work.js
    |--> `router.post("/login", login)`
    |-->` router.get("/getAllPost", getAllPost)`
```

Output: Post: ["createUser", "addTask", "login" ]
Get:  ["getAllPost" ]

Comment: There is no way to get the list of defined routes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all registered routes in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934452/how-to-get-all-registered-routes-in-express)